Number of $3 \times 3$ matrices with entries in $\{0, 1\}$ such that $A^2 = 0$
I'm working on the following problem:
Let $S$ be the set of all $3 \times 3$ matrices $A$ such that $A^2 = 0$ and
the entries of $A$ belong to $\{0, 1\}$. Find the number of elements in the set $S$.
Here's my approach so far:
Let's represent a general $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ as:
$A = \begin{bmatrix} 
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i
\end{bmatrix}$
where $a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i$ are either $0$ or $1$.
For $A^2$ to be the zero matrix, each entry of $A^2$ must be zero. This gives us the following conditions:
$1. a^2 + bd + cg = 0$
$2. ab + be + ch = 0$
$3. ac + bf + ci = 0$
$4. ad + de + fg = 0$
$5. bd + e^2 + fh = 0$
$6. cd + ef + fi = 0$
$7. ag + dh + gi = 0$
$8. bg + eh + hi = 0$
$9. cg + fh + i^2 = 0$
I'm not sure how to proceed from here. How can I use these conditions to count the number of valid matrices? Are there any patterns or simplifications I should look for? Should I use a totally different but simplified approach? How should I do this in limited time setting?

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Did you note that $a^2+bd+cg=0\implies a=0, bd=0, cg=0$?

You can simply observe that the entries of your matrices must be nonnegative. And so your equations give you more information:
$$a=e=i=0, \qquad bd=bf=bg=cg=ch=cd=fg=fh=...=0. $$
Can you continue?

Thank you for the hint. Here's my updated reasoning:


As $a = e = i = 0$, all diagonal elements are 0.


The conditions $bd = bf = bg = cg = ch = cd = fg = fh = ...=0$ restrict where 1's can appear.


Valid matrices $A$ where $A^2 = 0$:

6 matrices with a single 1 in a non-diagonal position
5 matrices with two 1's in pairs: $(b,h)$, $(c,f)$, $(d,g)$, $(g,h)$, $(b,c)$
1 null matrix



Total count: $6 + 5 + 1 = 12$ matrices


Is this correct? Have I missed any possibilities?
